# Using performseguewithidentifier to tab view controller

Tags: ios5

I have a login screen UIViewController and when the login button is clicked i want it to open the tab bar controller, i'm using performseguewithidentifier i created a push relationship with the storyboard, but when i do call performseguewithidentifier the tab bar does not display instead the screen is still the login screen, does anyone know what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and make sure your Segue Style is "Modal" and not "Push."  If you chose Push, it will not work unless you also have a Navigation controller.

Comment: it took me awhile to track this down. why is this the case?